# How do you sign up for the Bakkt exchange to trade Bitcoin Futures?

Tags: futures

With the recent launch of the Bakkt exchange. How do you sign up for this exchange or is this exclusively for institutions and not for individuals? There is no sign up option anywhere on their site.

Comment: It seems that Bakkt is only for institutions like big banks or companies and not for retail traders.